# after installing sinopia npm is not working

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, sinopia

Before installing sinopia everything working fine but after that npm fails. plz help me rolling back to original settings.
it got error whenever it try to install new npm package. for example. when i ran this

```
npm install -g mocha grunt-cli bower karma-cli

npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-34-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "mocha" "grunt-cli" "bower" "karma-cli"
npm ERR! node v4.4.5
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.5
npm ERR! code ECONNREFUSED
npm ERR! errno ECONNREFUSED
npm ERR! syscall connect

npm ERR! Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4873
npm ERR!     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:870:11)
npm ERR!     at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:893:20)
npm ERR!     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1061:14)
npm ERR!  { [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4873]
npm ERR!   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
npm ERR!   errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'connect',
npm ERR!   address: '127.0.0.1',
npm ERR!   port: 4873 }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/owaishanif/huble/meetings/npm-debug.log
```

here is my sinopia config file

```
#
# This is the default config file. It allows all users to do anything,
# so don't use it on production systems.
#
# Look here for more config file examples:
# https://github.com/rlidwka/sinopia/tree/master/conf
#

# path to a directory with all packages
storage: /home/owaishanif/.local/share/sinopia/storage

auth:
  htpasswd:
    file: ./htpasswd
    # Maximum amount of users allowed to register, defaults to "+inf".
    # You can set this to -1 to disable registration.
    #max_users: 1000

# a list of other known repositories we can talk to
uplinks:
  npmjs:
    url: https://registry.npmjs.org/

packages:
  '@*/*':
    # scoped packages
    access: $all
    publish: $authenticated

  '*':
    # allow all users (including non-authenticated users) to read and
    # publish all packages
    #
    # you can specify usernames/groupnames (depending on your auth plugin)
    # and three keywords: "$all", "$anonymous", "$authenticated"
    access: $all

    # allow all known users to publish packages
    # (anyone can register by default, remember?)
    publish: $authenticated

    # if package is not available locally, proxy requests to 'npmjs' registry
    proxy: npmjs

# log settings
logs:
  - {type: stdout, format: pretty, level: http}
  #- {type: file, path: sinopia.log, level: info}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To refer the standard npm registry rather than you own, you can run

```
npm set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

This will update your .npmrc config file.

Answer (score 0):

after playing lot with siopia finally i changed manully `~/.npmrc` file and commented this line.

```
registery=http://localhost:4873
```

now everything is working as packages are being installed without problem. there still workaround required for completely removing sinopia effect.